# Facebook sharing test on localhost

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I load the FB SDK and have the following function (below) to try and share to facebook.

```
   $(document).on("click",".xxx",function(event) {
      FB.ui(
          {
             method: 'share',
             href: 'http://localhost:8000',// The link in feed method
             title: 'Testing',  // The same than name in feed method
             picture: 'http://localhost:8000/static/images/l.jpg',  
              caption: 'caption',  
              description: 'Test description',
           },
           function(response){
              // your code to manage the response
           });
   });
```

It fails with the below error message:

[image]

I'm aware the FB can't read my localhost to retrieve any values it might need. Does anyone know how I can get this to work for testing purposes. Or would it just be easier to get a live environment going at this point?

Comment: You need someway for Facebook to scrape the URL you are trying to share

Comment: Well you can perhaps set something up with a DynDNS domain name or similar. But personally, I never went through that effort for this specific purpose; testing OG functionality from the staging system was usually enough.

Comment: ok thanks guys i think i need to move from localhost at this point cheers

Answer (score 0):

I use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/)
to simulate my local notebook as a server, it allows other people to access to my local web application via internet and it works for me to get through development time.

So, ngrok may be one of your choices.

Comment: Using ngrok, you will face the problem that Facebook OpenGraph Crawler can not reach to our localhost,as detailed in this link:

https://github.com/inconshreveable/ngrok/issues/445

but,using ngrok, at least you can share some basic information via Facebook share button.